# さくらのVPS＋nginxで、mosquittoブローカーにMQTT over WebSocketで接続できない(AMQJS0007E Socket error:undefined.)

Tags: nginx, websocket, mqtt

さくらのVPS上で、MQTT over WebSocketでmosquittoブローカーにsubscribeし、Webページにsubscribeした内容を表示するプログラムを作ろうと思っていますが、firefoxの開発者ツール内で以下のエラーが出てしまいます。Webページでのsubscribeにはmqttws31.min.jsを使用しました。 VSCodeの拡張機能Live Serverを使いローカルで動かしたときには問題なく動きます(追記：ローカルのnginxでも動きました)。個人的にはnginxのリバースプロキシ設定が怪しい気がしたのですが、どこが間違っているのか分かりませんでした…

どのようにすれば、さくらのVPS上でWebSocketを用いてMQTT通信ができるのでしょうか？初学者なので色々勘違いしているかもしれませんが、どなたかご教授いただけましたら幸いです。よろしくお願い致します。

【エラー内容】

```
CONNECT TO : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx : 9090
ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9090/ws のサーバーへの接続を確立できませんでした。
ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9090/ws のサーバーへの接続を確立できませんでした。
CONNECTION FAILURE - AMQJS0007E Socket error:undefined.
```

【環境】

- さくらのVPS（OS：Ubuntu）
- ブラウザ：Firefox(Chromeでも同様)
- nginx/1.18.0

【行ったこと】

- さくらのVPSでパケットフィルターの設定

  - Web | TCP 80/443
  - カスタム | TCP 9090
- ufwの設定

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
1883/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
9090/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
1883/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
9090/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

- mosquitto.confの設定

```
allow_anonymous true 

listener 1883

listener 9090
protocol websockets
```

- mosquitto.logの確認

```
1700453342: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1700453342: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1700453342: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1700453342: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9090.
1700453342: mosquitto version 2.0.11 running
```

- /etc/nginx/conf.d/server.conf の設定

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /ws {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9090;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

- index.html（subscribe用のWebページ）

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>            
</head>
<body>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
var wsbroker = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"; 
var wsport = 9090;

var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(wsbroker, wsport, "/ws", "myclientid_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));

client.onConnectionLost = function (responseObject) {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "CONNECTION LOST - " + responseObject.errorMessage;
};

client.onMessageArrived = function (message) {
  var outputMessage =
    "Receive Topic: " + message.destinationName +
    ' PAYLOAD: ' + message.payloadString;

  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = outputMessage;
  console.log(outputMessage);
}

var options = {
  timeout : 3,
  onSuccess: function () {
    var successMessage = "CONNECTION SUCCESS";
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = successMessage;
    console.log(successMessage);
    client.subscribe("topic/#");
  },
  onFailure: function (message) {
    var failureMessage = "CONNECTION FAILURE - " + message.errorMessage;
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = failureMessage;
    console.log(failureMessage);
  }
};

var connectMessage = "CONNECT TO : " + wsbroker + " : " + wsport;
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = connectMessage;
console.log(connectMessage);

client.connect(options);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

【追記 2023/11/22】
開発者ツールで、ローカルの場合とVPSでの場合それぞれの要求ヘッダーを見ると冒頭部分が異なりました。

- ローカル

```
GET /ws HTTP/1.1
```

- VPS

```
GET /ws undefined
```